# What is the $2012th$ number in this pattern?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, pattern-recognition

This is question 30 from Australian Maths 2012

$(0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,2,3,4,...)$

What is the $2012th $ number in this list?

What I did:

I broke up the first few numbers into smaller parts to identify the pattern

$(0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4)$

$(1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5)$

From this,I can see that every 9 numbers,the pattern restarts.

So, the $2012th$ number should be in the $\frac {2012}{9} th $ group which is the $223 \frac {5}{9} th$ group.

So,the first number in the $223 th $ group is $(223-1)$.

And to further break it up to make it easier to find the $2012th$ number.

From,$(0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4)$

$(0,1,2)$-$x$

$(1,2,3)$-$y$

$(2,3,4)$-$z$

The last number number in $x$ is the $2nd$ number in $y$,which is also the first number in $z$.

So,$222+2 =224$ is my answer.

However,checking the answer key I got,the answer is $9$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Actually, it is [sum of digits of (n written in base 3)](https://oeis.org/A053735). But I do not find any fault in your interpretation of the pattern.

Comment: This is the problem of this type of questions. Sometimes there are two ways to interpret a pattern.

Comment: Sequence solver didn't find anything particular: http://alteredqualia.com/visualization/hn/sequence/ And as Kenny indicates, there is more than one way to interpret a possible candidate

Comment: @Kenny Lau Why does it start back at 1 for the pattern at the link?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi because the link starts the pattern at 1?

Comment: The 28th number is $1$ ?.I don't understand...

Comment: My link doesn't start the pattern at 1. It starts the pattern at 0.

Comment: The 28th number is the sum of digits of (27 written in base 3), which is the sum of digits of ($1000_3$), which is $1+0+0+0=1$.

Comment: sum of digits of (n written in base 3) ,what does that mean?I lost at understanding the explanation at the link...

Comment: Counting in base 3: 0,1,2,10,11,12,20,21,22,100,101,102,120 etc. That is using only the digits 0,1 and 2. Adding up the digits is: 0,1,2,1,2,3,2....etc. so 2011 in base three is $2*3^6 + 2*3^5 + 0×3^4 +2*3^3 + 1* 3^2 + 1*3 + 1 = 2202111_3$. The sum of those digits is 9. So that is you solution. It's obviously not the solution in mind.  It,s not the one I had in mind either but there are more than one.

Comment: So,if we count in base $10$,it's actually following ${0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11...}$,so we just have to count the $2012th$ number which is $2011$,then convert it into base $10$ ?

Comment: I don't follow how you got that the pattern repeats every 9 terms or what the terms are.

Comment: $(0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4) +1 =(1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5)$ That's how I identify the pattern I guess?

Comment: That works because $9=3^2$ and you have a leading digit of $1$ for the numbers $9-17$.  It will be one more for numbers $18-26$ because $18=2\cdot 3^2$.  It will fail at $27$.  The second $27$ numbers will be one more than the first $27$ numbers.

Comment: Ah, I see your pattern.  It was the authors intent that not that the pattern is 9, but that it gets longer and longer.  The first is 1,2.  Then 123234.  Then 123234345234345456.  And so on.  The next pattern is 54 long and each pattern is 3 longer than the one before.

Comment: From the given pattern above,my rule will fail at 27?Okay,but this is for the Secondary 3 and 4 level,which I think is around for the first and second year of high school.I don't think we know that what base-10 number patterns and base-60 number patterns are.

Comment: But your pattern can be legitimately argued.  And is probably easier to see.

Comment: The link to the original question is here.I cut down the wordings because I thought they weren't that important but does the wording of the question make a difference? http://files.chiuchang.org.tw:8080/MyWeb/download/docu/AMC/12AMC/12Int.pdf

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C2%2C3%2C4&language=english&go=Search) finds it.

Comment: I have posted another question on it.But without computers to help,supposedly,this is a competition question,what do I know it's that pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you write the nonnegative integers in base $3$
$0,1,2,10,11,12,20,21,22,100,101,102,110,111,112,120,\dots$
Then you add up the (base 3) digits in each number (presumably in base $10$) 
$0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,2,3,4,3,\dots$
Since we start from zero, we express $2011$ in base $3$, getting $2202111_3$, then add the digits to get $9$.

Comment: Why is it after $0,1,2$,it is not $3$?

Comment: Because we are working in base $3$, so we can only use the digits $0,1,2$. Each place represents a factor $3$ more than the last (not $10$ as in base $10$).  So $12021_3=1\cdot 3^4+2 \cdot 3^3 + 0 \cdot 3^2 + 2 \cdot 3^1+1\cdot 3^0=115_{10}$  Binary (base $2$) uses powers of $2$ and digits $0,1$ the same way

Comment: So,$2011$ which is in base $10$,to get base $3$ ,it's $2 \cdot 10^4 +10^2 +10$ to get $2202111$.Then $2+2+2+1+1+1 =9$ ?

Comment: And how do you know to express $2011$ ?instead of other numbers?

Comment: You could read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Mathematics) on other bases.  To express $2011_{10}$ in base $3$, the ones digit is the remainder on dividing by $3$, which is $1$.  Then the quotient is $670$, which has remainder $1$ on dividing by $3$.  You get each digit in turn, going upwards.  It isn't easy if you haven't seen it before.

Comment: Hmmm,how can we identify if the pattern is following the 'base-numbers' pattern?

Comment: Only by seeing enough numbers to convince you.  All these sequence puzzles can be continued in infinitely many ways.  To have a unique solution, you need to count on the setter to have used the "simplest" rule that matches the data, and for your evaluation of "simplest" to be the same as the setter's.  As you are not familiar with base $3$, it doesn't appear simple to you. I think your rule does not explain the $5$ in the data.

Comment: I took the op pattern to be (n,n+1,n+2,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+2,n+3,n+4) iterated again and again and that does account for the 5.  It agrees with the intended answer for the first 18 terms as 9-17 in bad 3 is just 0-8 with a leading 1.  It doesn't show how the first nine terms were figured though.

Comment: How the first 9 terms were figured out?For the 1st term it's 0,the 10th term is 1,the 19th is 2.So,the 28th should be 3 and so on.That's how I assumed it.Furthermore,the first 9 terms can be broken down into 3 smaller parts.

Comment: You have defined a different rule for the sequence.  It matches the numbers we have been given, but is not the one the problem setter had in mind.  In the setter's sequence, the $28$th term comes from summing the digits of $27_{10}=1000_3$ and getting $1$.  The two rules agree on the first $27$ terms.  Choosing the correct rule can be difficult.  I think the setter's rule is better for someone familiar with other bases, but yours clearly is reasonable as well.

Comment: And this is competition question,great!!!Do I still get the marks or nope?

Comment: That depends on the competition.  I suspect not.  Usually, if you don't get their rule, you don't get the points.  If it were a class and you explained how you were thinking, you would have a better shot, assuming the teacher takes time to understand your answer.

Comment: Hahaha thanks for your help still!

Answer (score 0):

If you graph this sequence of numbers, you will find an interesting curve:

(0,1,2), (1,2,3), (2,3,4), -> first cycle

(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5), -> second cycle

(2,3,4), ...

Use Excel or squared paper.

Comment: It's a linear equation right.From the looks of the coordinates