# How do I identify pattern of different bases? For example, base $3$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Recently,I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1839869/307825) on number patterns.Turns out it wasn't the usual number pattern question.It was the sum of the digits at base 3.

How do I identify such number patterns or even know that it's at a different base?I can't really conclude that it's a number pattern of a sum of digits at a different base just by looking at it right?Any advice on such questions?

For example,

$(0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,2,3,4,...)$

Supposedly,that is the sum of digits of n at base 3.How can I identify such patterns?

Comment: Questions of the form "what is the next number in this sequence?" and "spot the pattern" are basically just glorified versions of the question "what number am I thinking about now?" It's just as much an exercise in mind reading as it is in mathematics. There are so _incredibly_ many, relatively simple patterns you can make that trying to identify which one has been used is next to impossible, unless you have some form of hint that can tell you where to start looking. That being said, try [oeis.org](http://oeis.org/A053735) next time.

Comment: Q30.The question is solved already.But I don't see how,in any way,you can see that it's a pattern in base 3.

http://files.chiuchang.org.tw:8080/MyWeb/download/docu/AMC/12AMC/12Int.pdf

Comment: oeis has the pattern.But let's say,it's a competition question without calculator.There is not way,that I can,in any sense,see that pattern,without any help from computers.

Comment: @Arthur: While I generally agree with you, for sequences that are simple enough compared to the length of the given initial segment, it makes sense to be able to compare solutions and decide if one is better than another, which we can do as described in my answer. The hardest to solve would probably be cryptographically secure PRNGs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up Kolmogorov complexity. One can fix a programming language and then define the answer to such pattern-continuation questions as the shortest program $P$ such that $P(0),P(1),\cdots$ agrees with the given terms. Now in general it is impossible to systematically find such a program, which means that we cannot hope to solve all except the simplest questions, but at least we can compare solutions according to this standard to see which is simpler.

Suppose we choose Javascript (as of today) as the programming language, and the required program must be named `f` and take a single variable as input. Then for the pattern in your question, your proposed solution would be `f=function(n){return n==0?0:n%3+f((n-n%3)/3)}`, indeed quite short! It wins
`f=function(n){return [0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4][n%9]+(n-n%9)/9}`, and I guess it would win all others too, since the sequence you gave is rather long.

Now how to guess the solution? Well the first observation is that it splits into triples of increasing consecutive numbers starting with "0,1,2" and "1,2,3" and "2,3,4", and if you look at the starting number of each triple it is "0,1,2,1,2,3,2" which looks exactly like the sequence itself! This is sufficient to generate the whole pattern, because we start with "0", and then replace each term $x$ by a triple "$x,x+1,x+2$", and repeat this as many times as we want:

> $0$
>
> $0,1,2$
>
> $0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4$
>
> $0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6$
>
> ...

Since this generates the pattern we desire, and is quite simple, we can justifiably say that it is 'the right solution'. It turns out that this
is equivalent to the base-3 interpretation that you mention in your question. Here's why.

The base-3 interpretation would mean that the desired function $f$ satisfies:

> $f(3n) = f(n)$ for any natural $n$.
>
> $f(3n+1) = f(n)+1$ for any natural $n$.
>
> $f(3n+2) = f(n)+2$ for any natural $n$.

Now notice that this is exactly what the other interpretation does! The triple at positions $3n,3n+1,3n+2$ in the sequence is generated from the term at position $n$, where $f(n)$ was replaced by $f(n),f(n)+1,f(n)+2$. Therefore the two interpretations give the same sequence.

Which interpretation you prefer is subjective. Some people would argue that "sum of digits in base-3" is simpler than my replacement interpretation, but that is only if you already know the notion of "base-3"! If you have to give an explanation of base-3 notation it would be longer than the description of my interpretation, so mine wins. That really is the whole point of using a fixed programming language, which just means that you have to do by yourself everything the programming language does not know. It essentially forces you to define everything except a fixed set of basic notions.

Comment: What if we manually look at the pattern?Is there a way?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: Doesn't my last paragraph answer that question?

Comment: I thought that part was after you used the program?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: You should read it before asking about it.

Comment: Okay,sorry I'm bad at maths,but how did you get the proposed solution?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: Specify which line in my last paragraph you didn't grasp. And if you don't know what are programs, read up on them. It's futile to try to understand this kind of pattern-finding techniques if you don't even know programming. I didn't use any program to find the two programs that I gave in my answer; I used my head. As I stated in my answer, **there is no systematic way to find the shortest program**, which also implies that there is no program to solve pattern-finding questions in general.

Comment: I understand that the proposed solution gives me the same numbers as the pattern given.Sorry,really really sorry,but the thing is that the pattern is for a secondary 3(the first year of high school,I think) competition question,which does not allow calculators.Also,how do you know it's base-3?I understand that patterns have lots of possible solutions,so the answer must be one that's simpler among the 2 I think?Sorry,I don't know programming!Never learn it before.I think I'm really lost at your answer.That's what I know and what I don't understand from your paragraph.I'm sorry.

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: Okay I've added details. You got the right idea that we want to choose the simplest solution, but there is no way to define "simplest" without using some kind of programming language. (Do learn programming if you can; it will really improve your clarity of thought in every subject, not only mathematics.) If any part is still unclear, just ask again.

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: By the way, the second program I gave is equivalent to your repeat-every-9 interpretation in your linked question, so it loses (by a few bytes) to the base-3 interpretation based on Javascript.

Comment: Sorry,I understood everything so far,except the 3rd paragraph!Finally.Yes!

'it splits into triplets....itself.'that part I'm lost a bit.I understand why it can break into triplets but I don't understand why if it matches the sequence,we must replace '$x$' with '$x,x+1,x+2$' ?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: Hmm we're attempting to reverse the process. Our human brain tells us that we can simplify the pattern because they come in triples of a special form and so we only need to know the first of every triple. When we take that we find that it's the same as the original sequence, which means that if we have the first $k$ terms in the original sequence we can get the first $3k$ terms. How? By replacing each term with the appropriate triple to reverse the observed simplification process.

Comment: Wow,thank you so much,I really need to learn programming soon if it can help see such things.Thank you so much!I understand this fully now!

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: Great to hear that. I recommend starting with the Python programming language. Javascript is the most common language used by websites, which every modern browser can execute, but it has too many oddities that may make learning it frustrating. I don't have any idea what is a good place to learn Python though, since I learnt it only after a few other languages.

Comment: Oh yes,now that I can identify patterns like this to some extent.How to find the $n$th term in the pattern now?I think there would be around $671$ replacements before we can include the $2012$th term.

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: Nope. Every replacement causes the number of terms to grow by $3$ times, so after the $k$-th iteration the sequence has length $3^k$. Just $7$ iterations give you $2187$ terms.

Comment: Oh,the $k$th sequence would be longer 3 times longer than the previous sequence.Sorry my mistake.I just assumed and divided by 3.

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: No problem. It takes time to get used to such things. No hurry. =)

Comment: So to find the $n$th term,we can just find many iteration and trace the source?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: Yup. Or you first use the reasoning I gave to see that it's the same as the base-3 interpretation and then compute the answer by converting $n$ to base-3.